# Select sum and group by kind

Tags: php, mysql, json, morris.js

I'm trying to fill the data array for a Morris Chart with data from my MySql Database.

I have the table 'buchungen' like this:

```
ID   Value   Kind   Date
1    200     L      2016-01-01
2    250     B      2016-01-01
3    250     L      2016-01-01
4    200     B      2016-02-01
5    250     B      2016-02-01
6    200     L      2016-02-01
```

I want to do a query that gives me output like this:

Sum of value, grouped by data and kind.

For January: 450, L and  250 B

For February: 450 B and 200 L

The needed structure:

```
[{"m":"1","a":"450","b":"250},{"m":"2","a":"200","b":"450}]
```

With my query:

```
SELECT MONTH( date ) AS m, SUM( value ) AS a
FROM  `buchungen`
WHERE YEAR( date ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) )
GROUP BY MONTH( date )
```

I get the following structure:

```
[{"m":"4","a":"476852.64"},{"m":"5","a":"851866.74"}]
```

I have the problem that I don't know how to consider the 'kind' field. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MONTH( date ) AS m, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Kind = 'L' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS a,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Kind = 'B' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS b
FROM  `buchungen`
WHERE YEAR( date ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) )
GROUP BY MONTH( date )
```

Comment: While a bit of a mouthful, I guess `WHERE date BETWEEN CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-01-01') AND CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-12-31')` would be faster

Comment: This is working fine. Thanks! Is there also a way to output the values for 'empty' months? Like if there was nothing in 'buchungen' for january just output month 01, a 0, b 0?

Comment: @FlorianSauerwein You have to use a calendar table for this.

Comment: I have a table for all months. And I probably have to do an outer join on that table. Can I just extend the above query or do i have to make a complete new one?

Comment: @FlorianSauerwein You can do sth like `..FROM Calendar c LEFT JOIN buchungen b ON c.month = b.MONTH(date)..`

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you want Sum of value, grouped by date and kind, try this:

```
SELECT MONTH( date ) AS m, kind, SUM( value ) AS a FROM  `buchungen` WHERE YEAR( date ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) ) GROUP BY MONTH( date ), kind;
```